# bootstrap, re-arranging divs under the mobile view.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have run into an interesting situation in which I have two columns, and two divs within each column.  The problem that I am having is that when I need to scale down the window to the mobile view, I need two divs from the second and third column to be interchanged.

Example (I'm using haml)

```
col-sm-8
 %h1 "A"
 %h1 "B"

col-sm-4
 %h1 "C"
 %h1 "D"
```

So basically this would look like this
AA C
BB D

But when I want to condense it, It looks like

A

B

C

D

And here is the thing, when I want this condensed, I want the columns to appear like:

A

C

B

D

Does anybody have any ideas on how to go about with this one?

Comment: It's impossible to even re-order them using `display:flex` because you have the elements wrapped under different containers. You should be able to re-order them if they all uses the same parent. If that's the case then, 
`parent{ display:flex; flex-direction:column;} .a{ order: 1}  .b{ order: 2}` ..etc. Be sure to put the vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by faking it with pulling and pushing certain columns at different sizes. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering. Basically, you will pull or push the columns at larger sizes but for mobile devices have no pushing or pulling and have the columns in the order that you want them to appear.

So the html page should be ordered such as A, C, B, D; then use pushing and pulling for sm or md and larger to arrange them as you please on larger screens. I am unaware if pushing and pulling more than 2 columns will work. If it does not, you could always make nested columns, such that A and C will be in their own new column and container and B and D will do the same but on the left side of the screen.

Comment: So I am managing to get it set so that it appears as A B C D, and when responsive It appears as B A D C. I was able to do this via push pull methods, and its cool, but the root of my problem is responsively I need it to appear as A, C, B, D.  I did look into nesting, but it caused issues with the overall design because these div's aren't all the same size.  

Does that explanation of the issue make sense?

Comment: yes this makes sense. I'm unaware of how much content will be loaded into these sections, but if the overhead will be minimal you may need to consider using the visible and hidden classes on B and C so that you can alternate them. When on mobile you could hide the old B section and show the new C in its place and vice versa for the other section.

Comment: Yeah that is probably the best way to go about with this one. Thanks for the help!